# I need to save my returns to get the plot, occuDF is a DataFrame and occuList is a list

Tags: python, function, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def csv_til_liste(filname):
    occuDF = pd.read_csv(filname)
    occuList=occuDF.values.tolist()
    return occuDF, occuList

occuDF.boxplot(column = 'Temperature', by = 'Occupancy');
plt.suptitle('')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the method and save it in 2 separate variables:

```
df, l = csv_til_liste('a.csv')
df.boxplot(column = 'Temperature', by = 'Occupancy')
plt.suptitle('')
```